# Any mobile devices between this viewport size range?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

Hi I wanted to ask if there are any common mobile devices that have viewport size between 520px - 768px ?

768 px of course is the popular Apple ipad. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget that laptop etc users can set their viewports how they want...

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you will change the device orientation to landscape, a lot of them will fall under that category.